# What is the standard COBOL RANDOM function implementation?

Tags: cobol, cobol85

The COBOL `RANDOM` function documentation doesn't give sufficient information on the range of accepted values for `argument-1`.

Perhaps someone can shed light on my following questions:

- What range of seed values is accepted?
- How are values treated that are exceeding the allowed range?

  - Are they truncated?
  - Are only the lower bits used?
  - Or the upper bits?
  - Are the leftmost digits used?
  - Or the rightmost?
  - How many of them?
  - Is a `MOD` function applied to the seed value?

In short:

**Is there a specification in the COBOL standard defining which digits of a value like `01 myRandomSeed PIC 9(50).` are being used?**

[image: Large value demonstration]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the COBOL standard have a look at [the current draft standard](https://isotc.iso.org/livelink/livelink?func=ll&objId=19468956) (the files available there vary depending on the current state of the committee work), which has the `RANDOM` function under "15 intrinsic functions".

The format is:

```
FUNCTION RANDOM [ (  [ argument-1 ]  ) ]
```

With the rules that the optional argument-1 shall be of class numeric and either be zero or a positive integer.

For the returned value:

> The implementor shall specify the subset of the domain of argument-1 values that will yield distinct sequences of pseudo-random numbers. This subset shall include the values from 0 through at least 32767.

Comment: You're right. Sorry for my mistake. I updated my question accordingly. Thanks for pointing me to the specification!